Azure AD groups and group members avoiding other groups as members
I'm trying to pull together a report of all the members that are inside specific Azure AD groups , everything works fine until one of the members is another AD group instead of a regular username. On the following picture, the row # 3 has Username and UserPrincipalName blank because the UserId is actually a group ID

Below is the powershell I'm running in Azure runbook POwershell 7.2

$resultsarray =@()
$groups = get-mggroup -All |  Where-Object {$.DisplayName -eq 'MT'
-or $.DisplayName -like 'MT_ *'}
ForEach ($group in $groups) { $members = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId
$group.Id ForEach ($member in $members) {
$username = (get-mguser -UserId $member.Id).DisplayName
$principalusername = (get-mguser -UserId $member.Id).UserPrincipalName
$UserObject = new-object PSObject $UserObject | add-member
-membertype NoteProperty -name "GroupId" -Value $group.Id $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "GroupName" -Value
$group.DisplayName $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty
-name "UserId" -Value $member.Id $UserObject | add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserName" -Value $username    $UserObject |
add-member  -membertype NoteProperty -name "UserPrincipalName" -Value
$principalusername $resultsarray += $UserObject
}
}
$resultsarray | Export-CSV -Encoding ASCII
($env:TEMP2+"ADGroupsANDUsers.csv") -Notype
$Context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName 'teststorage01'
Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $Context -Container "test" -File
($env:TEMP2+"ADGroupsANDUsers.csv") -Blob "ADGroupsANDUsers.csv"
-Force

This is just an idea how to get the users the member of an AD group is another AD group but you guys might have a better solution , I just need some guidance on the ideal solution on this type of scenario.  I wish I can tell everyone to not add an AD group as member of another AD group :(

I'm looking for the ideal powershell code to handle this situation

your ideal output becomes flawed as soon as the nesting of groups have more depth. the api that can get you all members of a group recursively is the transitive members API as for how the output should look is not for us to decide that

Thanks Santiago, I've replaced the tramsitive member command and that is getting the AD group  + all members inside that group . This is what I need because the Subscription permissions only show the main AD group assigned and now I can know how many users have that RBAC

Based on Santiago Squarzon comment , I've replaced the code
$members = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $group.Id

With
$members = Get-MgGroupTransitiveMember -GroupId $group.Id

Now I'm able to see all nested real usernames behind the AD group that it is part of the main AD group and so on.

Remember to always include -All when calling this endpoint otherwise you might just end up with the first page of the api response
